# When does Devon Carter learn about Raven Baxter's psychic abilities?

Tags: ravens-home, thats-so-raven

In Raven's Home S02E01-2:

> Raven and Booker tell each other that they have visions.

From Raven's Home S02E03:

> Booker: Why can't I tell people that I'm psychic?
>  Raven: You can. As long as you trust them. Like I trust Chelsea, and your dad.

---

When does Devon learn Raven is psychic? Guesses:

1. During That's So Raven
2. Between finale of That's So Raven and start of Raven's Home but excluding Cory in the House
3. Between finale of That's So Raven and start of Raven's Home, namely during Cory in the House (unlikely)
4. Sometime during Raven's Home (unlikely)
5. Never. Explanation in spoiler tag:

> Raven trusts Devon but doesn't tell him. Trust is a necessary but not sufficient condition for telling Devon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in (a later episode) Sorry to Father You, S03E15 of Raven's Home.

> Booker tells Devon about Booker's visions and then Raven and Devon later tell Booker about how Raven told Devon: Raven told Devon sometime before the events of Raven's Home and sometime after the events of That's So Raven.